# Conditionally determining value of column by looking at last group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have test data that looks like this:

```
   Group Value
1      a     1
2      a     2
3      a     3
4      a     4
5      b     5
6      b     2
7      b     3
8      c     6
9      c     7
10     c     8
11     c     3
12     c     6
13     d     9
14     d    10
15     e     9
```

I am trying to create a vectorized approach, preferably using `tidyverse` tools that will create an additional column that notes if the Value is present in the previous grouping. Here is an example of how this would look like:

```
   Group Value In_Last_Group
1      a     1         FALSE
2      a     2         FALSE
3      a     3         FALSE
4      a     4         FALSE
5      b     5         FALSE
6      b     2          TRUE
7      b     3          TRUE
8      c     6         FALSE
9      c     7         FALSE
10     c     8         FALSE
11     c     3          TRUE
12     c     5          TRUE
13     d     9         FALSE
14     d    10         FALSE
15     e     9          TRUE
```

I have a way to do this using a standard for loop, but I have a large dataset and I believe it would be much faster if it was vectorized. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the `dput` of the test data:

```
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 
8, 3, 6, 9, 10, 9)), .Names = c("Group", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `nest` after grouping by 'Group', then remove the first and last elements of the 'data' column, use `map2` to do a comparison of corresponding elements and then append with the `FALSE` elements for the first group

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         group_by(Group) %>%
         nest

flag <-  map2(df2$data[-1], df2$data[-nrow(df2)], ~ 
      .x$Value %in% .y$Value) %>%
      unlist
df1$Last_Group <- c(rep(FALSE, nrow(df2$data[[1]])), flag)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a join to lookup values in the previous group to see if those values exists. It should be faster than looping through the groups. I am not familiar with `tidyverse` but here is an implementation in `data.table` (which should also be faster than `tidyverse` if your data is large enough):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, c("g", "pg") := .(r <- rleid(Group), r - 1L)]
DF[, ilg := FALSE][DF, on=.(pg=g, Value), ilg := TRUE]
```

output (note that there is a typo for Value in row 12 of OP's desired output):

```
    Group Value g pg   ilg
 1:     a     1 1  0 FALSE
 2:     a     2 1  0 FALSE
 3:     a     3 1  0 FALSE
 4:     a     4 1  0 FALSE
 5:     b     5 2  1 FALSE
 6:     b     2 2  1  TRUE
 7:     b     3 2  1  TRUE
 8:     c     6 3  2 FALSE
 9:     c     7 3  2 FALSE
10:     c     8 3  2 FALSE
11:     c     3 3  2  TRUE
12:     c     6 3  2 FALSE
13:     d     9 4  3 FALSE
14:     d    10 4  3 FALSE
15:     e     9 5  4  TRUE
```

data:

```
DF <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 
8, 3, 6, 9, 10, 9)), .Names = c("Group", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```